# Ошибка в синтаксисе команды возле оператора IF PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

помогите пожалуйста, пишет syntax error at or near "IF", уже не знаю что делать. Советы в инете не помогли, пишу сюда. Заранее спасибо

```
CREATE FUNCTION "FILM"."Actor_Select"
(
    "FilterFilmID" INT DEFAULT NULL
)
RETURNS setof "FILM"."Actors" AS 
$$
BEGIN
    IF "FilterFilmID" IS NULL THEN
        SELECT "FILM"."Actors"."ActorID", "FILM"."Actors"."Name", "FILM"."Actors"."Surname", "FILM"."Actors"."DateOfBirth" FROM "FILM"."Films"
        LEFT JOIN "FILM"."Films_Actors" ON "FILM"."Films_Actors"."FilmID" = "FILM"."Films"."FilmID"
        LEFT JOIN "FILM"."Actors" ON "FILM"."Films_Actors"."ActorID" = "FILM"."Actors"."ActorID";
    ELSE
        SELECT "FILM"."Actors"."ActorID", "FILM"."Actors"."Name", "FILM"."Actors"."Surname", "FILM"."Actors"."DateOfBirth" FROM "FILM"."Films"
        LEFT JOIN "FILM"."Films_Actors" ON "FILM"."Films_Actors"."FilmID" = $1
        LEFT JOIN "FILM"."Actors" ON "FILM"."Films_Actors"."ActorID" = "FILM"."Actors"."ActorID";
    END IF;
END
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Вы указываете в конце "LANGUAGE sql" но в sql нет конструкции IF, она есть только plpgsql

Comment: Только есть еще проблемы, в процедурном языке в функции должен быть return, а у вас его нет. Вы уж определитесь на каком языке пишите. Если на процедурном, то посмотрите как пишутся на нем процедуры возвращающие таблицы. А если на SQL то сделайте все одним запросом, там достаточно условие указать `where FilmID = "FilterFilmID" or "FilterFilmID" IS NULL` и не надо никаких IF. А еще что это вы такое написали во втором запросе в ON первого LEFT JOIN, откуда там $1 и главное вы убрали условие соединения таблиц, в итоге у вас таблицы перемножаться, вы получите на выдаче миллионы строк, все зависнет

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, $1 это обращение к "FilterFilmID", с plpgsql все работает отлично. Сейчас я вообще думаю над тем, что, скорее всего, это ветвление вообще не нужно, так как эта функция будет вызываться с каким-то аргументом, но на всякий случай я решил данную проверку сделать.